# Search for a String and Move 2 Values in that Row to New Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

I am looking to create a graph that shows each Area's score total (which is a row's columns D-I summed) vs. the date listed. My data is shown in the picture. What I would like to do is search for every time an Area appears in column A, then on a new sheet output the corresponding dates and sums of the scores for that Area. This would then allow me to use the two value table to make a simple graph. I have a system that automatically runs and inputs values at the top of the sheet I have attached. Is this possible?

My Datasheet:
[image: My Datasheet]

The ideal end goal for results table:
[image: The ideal end goal for results table]

Less ideal but acceptable results table. This would need to be done individually for each of the "Areas":
[image: Less ideal but acceptable results table. This would need to be done individually for each of the "Areas".]

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the resulting table looks like.

Comment: The end goal for the results table has been added. Thanks.